# LocalConnection passing by value or reference?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, localconnection

When using LocalConnection that have two SWFs talking back and forth to each other. Are objects passed by value or reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all communication between swf has to be pass by value (The actual parameter is fully evaluated and the resulting value is copied into a location being used to hold the formal parameter's value )  and not reference. Pass by reference will violate the sandbox in which each swf resides. ( since localconnection could be used between multiple swf files).

Anyways I am interested to know why do you ask? Are you checking if you need defensive copying. (that is why I decided to dig in this information myself.)

Comment: I have a very large flex app that has a data manager class. I have a main swf that spawns multiple child browser windows with separate swfs. Each swf needs access to that data oabject and it would be alot easier to preserve the data binding if it was passed by reference.

Comment: Plus the fact that LocalConnection has a 50k limit

Answer (score 2):

The data passed through a LocalConnection object is serialized to a file by the sender and then the receiver deserializes it, meaning it builds a new object.

The serialization protocol used is AMF, I think (if you map your class using `registerClassAlias` your objects will be received with the same type you passed; if you don't, you'll `Object` objects).

So, in the receiving swf you'll get a fresh copy of your object. Also, keep in mind that if you do map your classes, you must have a parameterless constructor or a constructor that only takes optional parameters; otherwise, your objects will throw an Error when the receiving party deserializes them.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much( didn't know about the AMF though ). Unfortunately, I need the data binding ability so I will have to just do it through call backs